# How to pass destination path while running .exe file from cmd

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, command-prompt, executable

I am running a .exe file. The exe file will ask for password and then it will ask for destination folder where it will generate on .csv file. I am trying to run this process from command prompt to automate the process using following command.

**[Path to .exe file] -p [password]**

How to provide the destination path as the argument or any options? I even tried following command

**START /D [Destination Folder] [Path to .exe file] -p [password]** but it still prompt for destination path.

according to flow first it will ask for password and then it will ask for destination path. With both commands i am able to skip the prompting of password but the path is still asked. I need any option in command like -path or -dir or -tarpath or something to pass path as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try things like `whatever.exe /?` or `whatever.exe -?` or `whatever.exe --help` and see if you get a help page.  If not, look for documentation from whoever wrote the executable in the first place.  Off-topic here anyway.  You might ask on Super User, but you'll need to at least say what executable you're talking about; there are a *lot* of applications out there, so we're not likely to be able to guess!

Comment: ... that said, you *could* try something like `echo destination-folder | whatever.exe -p password`